# How I can install GDB in NetBeans in Mavericks for debugging?

Tags: macos

I have an error when I debug a C program in NetBeans.

```
GDB has unexpectedly stopped with return 127
```

Here is a screenshot of the build tools:

[image: Build Tools]

Comment: Have you installed the Xcode command line tools? or looking at the tool collections why not use clang as Apple does nit supply a GNU compiler(gcc is a lnk to clang)

Comment: yes i already installed command line tools, ok i will try with the clang.

Answer (score 2):

That's what I did to install GDB (under Yosemite):

1. Install `brew`: http://brew.sh
2. Update `brew`. If you already have installed `brew`, check for updates. In the terminal:

```
$ brew update
```

This step turned out to be decisive for me as, before updating, `brew` did not find any `gdb` package:

```
$ brew install gdb # Error: No available formula for gdb
```

And after that:

```
$ brew update
$ brew search | grep gdb # cgdb gdb gdbm pgdbf
```

3. Install gdb:

```
$ brew install gdb
```

4. Codesign the binary following these instructions: http://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/BuildingOnDarwin I copy them here for the sake of completeness and to add some comments:

> **Creating a certificate**
>
> - Start Keychain Access application (`/Applications/Utilities/Keychain Access.app`)
> - Open menu `/Keychain Access/Certificate Assistant/Create a Certificate...`
> - Choose a name (`gdb-cert` in the example), set `Identity Type` to `Self Signed Root`, set `Certificate Type` to `Code Signing` and select the `Let me override defaults`. Click several times on `Continue` until you get to the `Specify a Location For The Certificate` screen, then set `Keychain` to `System`.
> - If you can't store the certificate in the `System` keychain, create it in the `login` keychain, then exported it. You can then imported it into the `System` keychain.
> - Finally, using the contextual menu for the certificate, select `Get Info`, open the `Trust` item, and set `Code Signing` to `Always Trust`.
> - You must quit Keychain Access application in order to use the certificate and restart `taskgated` service by killing the current running taskgated process (comment: for example with `sudo pkill taskgated` or restarting).

And then

> **Giving gdb permission to control other processes**
>
> If the certificate is known as `gdb-cert`, just use:
>
> ```
> $ codesign -s gdb-cert gdb
> ```
>
> Comment: if `gdb` is not found, then add the path where it was installed. In my case:
>
> ```
> $ codesign -s gdb-cert /usr/local/Cellar/gdb/7.10/bin/gdb
> ```

5. Use either `gdb` or the path where gdb was installed (for example, `/usr/local/Cellar/gdb/7.10/bin/gdb`) in the menu `/Netbeans/Preferences/C/C++/Build Tools` field `Debugger Command field`.